# How to insert values from a table in another along with other values in sql server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I'm working on a project in which i need to insert data from one table to another along with another value, lets say I have table1(col1,col2,col3) and i have table2(col2) so i wrote the following:-

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1,col2) VALUES ((@constant),(SELECT col2 FROM table2))
```

How to do that knowing that `@Constant` is a parameter that has a value used inside a stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1,col2) 
SELECT @constant, col2 
FROM table2
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me, I will choose your answer as the best answer once the site allows me :) thank you again:)

Comment: "I will choose your answer as the best answer" are you sure? The others also look good ;-)